# Chronicle Queue: StoreFileListener multiple onAcquired and onReleased

Tags: chronicle-queue

I am using Chronicle 4.5.27.

Below is simple implementation for Writer and Reader with StoreFileListner. In Reader I am getting multiple onAcquired and onReleased events.

Why will this happen? I am expecting to receive only one Acquire (when file is acquired for reading) and one Release (after read is complete).

In the below logs for Reader once can see multiple of onAcquired and onReleased events.

Please note this behaviour is random. Also note Writer has been deliberately slowed down with Jvm.pause so as to simulate real system where data might not be available continuously.

```
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.RollCycles;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.StoreFileListener;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueue;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ChronicleFactory {
    public SingleChronicleQueue createChronicle(String instance, String persistenceDir, RollCycles rollCycles) {
        SingleChronicleQueue chronicle = null;
        try {
            chronicle = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(persistenceDir).rollCycle(rollCycles).storeFileListener(new StoreFileListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReleased(int i, File file) {
                    String currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy‌​-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
                    System.out.println(currentTime + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " onReleased called for file: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " for cycle: " + i);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAcquired(int cycle, File file) {
                    String currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy‌​-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
                    System.out.println(currentTime + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " onAcquired called for file: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " for cycle: " + cycle);
                }
            }).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return chronicle;
    }
}

import net.openhft.chronicle.core.Jvm;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptAppender;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.RollCycles;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueue;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class MarketDataWriter {
    private static AtomicLong dataSeq = new AtomicLong();
    private static long longSequence = 0;
    private static int intSequence = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String path = "C:\\Logs\\ChronicleData\\marketdata";
        writeMarketData(path);
    }

    private static void writeMarketData(String path) {
        ChronicleFactory chronicleFactory = new ChronicleFactory();
        SingleChronicleQueue chronicle = chronicleFactory.createChronicle("MD", path, RollCycles.MINUTELY);

        ExcerptAppender appender = chronicle.acquireAppender();

        while (true) {
            Jvm.pause(100); //NOTE: Slowing down writer to understand file rolling
            appender.writeBytes(b -> {
                b.writeLong(getLongSequence());
                b.writeInt(getIntSequence());
            });
        }
    }

    private static long getLongSequence() {
        return longSequence++;
    }

    private static int getIntSequence() {
        return intSequence++;
    }
}

import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptTailer;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.RollCycles;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueue;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SimpleMarketDataReader {

    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pathForMarketData = "C:\\Logs\\ChronicleData\\marketdata";
        readMarketData(pathForMarketData);
    }

    public static void readMarketData(String pathForMarketDataFile) {
        ChronicleFactory chronicleFactory = new ChronicleFactory();
        SingleChronicleQueue chronicle = chronicleFactory.createChronicle("Reader", pathForMarketDataFile, RollCycles.MINUTELY);

        //Create another thread to read same file
        SimpleMarketDataReaderNewChronicle simpleMarketDataReaderNewChronicle = new SimpleMarketDataReaderNewChronicle();
        executor.submit(simpleMarketDataReaderNewChronicle);

        ExcerptTailer tailer = chronicle.createTailer();
        try {
            while (true) {
                tailer.readBytes(b -> {
                    b.readLong();
                    b.readInt();
                    //System.out.println("Long Sequence in SimpleMarketDataReader: " + b.readLong());
                    //System.out.println("User data is: " + userData);
                    //System.out.println("Int Sequence is: " + b.readInt());
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Writer Output**:

2018‌​-01-03 09:36:00.079: main onAcquired called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

2018‌​-01-03 09:37:00.098: main onReleased called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

**Reader Output**:

2018‌​-01-03 09:36:00.065: main onAcquired called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

2018‌​-01-03 09:36:00.075: main onReleased called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

2018‌​-01-03 09:36:00.078: main onAcquired called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

2018‌​-01-03 09:36:00.082: main onReleased called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

2018‌​-01-03 09:36:00.086: main onAcquired called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

2018‌​-01-03 09:37:00.103: main onReleased called for file: C:\Logs\ChronicleData\marketdata\20180103-0936.cq4for cycle: 25249536

Comment: This would need to be investigated further. Can you try version 4.6.60 as many bugs have been fixed?

Comment: I have tested with 4.6.59 and I have not seen the above problem in latest version. I have tried 4.6.60 on maven repository and it is still not avaialable https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.openhft/chronicle-queue. Can someone add me mailing list for the latest releases?

Comment: mvnrepository is a little slow. Using the maven search will be more up to date https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cchronicle%20queue The latest is 4.6.61 so I would try that.

Comment: I have started using 4.6.61 and don't see the behaviour of 4.5.27. Are you planning any further releases? I am not confident enough to promote 4.6.x to prod yet.

Comment: not today. We have planned enhancements though none I can think of which relate to your issue.